# Getting gap_init on new apache cordova install when viewing android app in browser

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I just recently installed apache cordova and am trying to get it up and running properly.  I'm using a macbook pro running 10.9.5.  My android SDK is the latest (22, but android target build uses 21).  The cordova version is the latest as well (4.3).  This issue occurs with any example app that I've tried, including the basic app/page that gets installed when you create a new cordova project (i.e. cordova create...).

For the most part, everything seems to be working ok, with one exception.  When I try to view the android version of the test app in a browser (any browser - tried chrome, firefox, safari), I get various prompts that show up on the init/load of the app.  The first prompt window to popup up says "gap_init:2", which is generated from the androidExec function in the cordova.js file:

```
androidExec.init = function() {
    bridgeSecret = +prompt('', 'gap_init:' + nativeToJsBridgeMode);
    channel.onNativeReady.fire();
};
```

If I cancel thru these prompts (there are 3 prompt windows), then the app seems to load ok.  If I 'ok' thru these prompts, then the app gets into an infinite cycle of processing empty messages, and I have to kill the browser processes to stop it.

The iOS version of the app loads fine in every browser.  I've tried changing the android target to version 19, but the prompts still occur.  There are no error messages during the build process.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be causing this?  How is this prompt message supposed to be caught/handled?

Comment: don't open an android app on the browser, the android code is for an android app. If you want to test on a browser add browser platform to your project and test that code generated. To add browser platform use this command: "cordova platform add browser"

Comment: thanks - that makes a lot more sense than what i was trying.

Comment: Hey! I'm having the same problem. Could you fixed?

Comment: Basically, you can't run the 'android' version of the app in the browser, you'll get the gap_init errors.  Instead run the 'browser' version of the app in the browser to do your testing.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, from visual studio, on running, it opens web pages for Android /iOS environment, you would have tried to cut-short the url to open for web version, this is when you will get dialog's as you mentioned.

To overcome this problem map the www folder to your local iis / iis express and open the url, page will open without any error.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The only problem was access rights that have to be properly set for the folder (for the application pool identity user). I am wondering if there is a way to set "Browser" target or something instead so that it runs of F5

Answer (score 1):

This error you get when you use the following command directly as follows:

```html
ionic serve
and then followed by 
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I SUGGEST TO FOLLOW THIS METHOD, IF YOU WANT TO RUN THE APP IN BROWSER

```html
ionic serve
ionic build
ionic build --prod
```

This way you get www folder where you can upload to server and check the whole app in browser directly